# French citizenship through UK-born father whose birth was registered as French outside France

Tags: france, citizenship, french-citizens

My father was born in the UK to a French mother (born in France), with his birth registered at the consulate as a French born outside of France. He has a French passport & CNIS. He has always been a dual national, French and British.

Would it be possible for me, born in the UK to a French-born-outside-France father, to obtain French citizenship if we now got my birth registered with the consulate in the same way? I understand there may be penalties for having not registered me as a child.